# java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type

Tags: java

Делал по книге HeadofFirst(стр 390) поймал ошибку в чём кроется проблема ?!

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - Erroneous sym type:
>   javax.swing.JButton.addActionListener     at
>   simplegui.Gui.go(Gui.java:23)     at
>   simplegui.SimpleGUI.main(SimpleGUI.java:18)
>       package simplegui;

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


/**
 *
 * @author hays
 */
public class Gui implements GuiInterface{
   private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   private  JButton button = new JButton("Click me !");    
    @Override
    public void go() {       
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.getContentPane().add(button);
       button.addActionListener(this); //Тут ругает  Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.swing.JButton.addActionListener
       frame.setSize(300,300);
       frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void actionPerfomerd(ActionEvent event)
    {
       button.setText("I've been clicked!");
    }
}


package simplegui;

public class SimpleGUI {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Gui Simplee = new Gui();
  Simplee.go(); // И тут Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.swing.JButton.addActionListener
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `addActionListener` принимает объекты типа `ActionListener`. Соотвественно, ваш класс Gui должен реализовывать этот интерфейс. Замените `public class Gui implements GuiInterface` на `public class Gui implements GuiInterface, ActionListener`.